# Can I implement an interface and override the return type of one of the interface's methods?

Tags: php, oop

I have a `Task` class that extends an abstract class, `TaskBase`.

```
// class Task
class Task extends TaskBase {
   /**
    * @var Processor
    */
    private $processor

    public function __construct(Processor $processor) 
    {
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    public function process() : ProcessResult
    {
        return  $this->processor->execute();
    }
}

// abstract class TaskBase

abstract class TaskBase implements CommanTask {
    protected function getKey(): string
    {
    }
}
```

This `TaskBase` implements an interface `CommanTask`, which contains the following method.

```
interface CommanTask {
  public function  process(): ProcessResult;
}
```

Now I need a new task class `TaskMultiple`, and it's `process()` method needs to return an array of `ProcessResult` instead of one `ProcessResult`.

How can I extend abstract class `TaskBase` for this new `TaskMultiple` class?

Comment: @yivi - I need this new class `TaskMultiple` which need to return an array of `ProcessResult` instead of one `ProcessResult`

Comment: @yivi - Yes I can create a new interface but my abstract `TaskBase` is implemented from `CommanTask`, So when I create a new interface how I can implement it in `TaskBase`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement an interface, you need to actually comply with the contract laid out by the interface.

The interface you propose says that `process()` returns a `ProcessResult`. If you could change that in an implementing class to returning an `array`, then consumers of the class wouldn't be able to trust the contract specified by the interface.

They would try to use the result of `TaskMultiple::process()`, and since they interface says it would return a `ProcessResult`, a fatal error would soon happen when it tried to treat it as such (e.g. by accessing a method for that class), and it wasn't that.

Your solutions are:

If you are on PHP 8, you could use union types:

```
interface Task {
  public function  process(): ProcessResult|iterable;
}
```

It would work, but it's ugly. Now consumers of the any `Task` implementing service would need to check on the result of `process()` to see if it's a single `ProcessResult`, or a collection (presumably of `ProcessResult`s).

If you are on PHP < 8, you *could* make it work simply by removing the type hint:

```
interface Task {
  public function  process()
}
```

Now consumers would only know that there is a `process()` method, but you'd have no type information at all. Uglier still.

Better, simply create different interfaces like `Task` and `MultipleTask`:

```
interface Task {
  public function  process(): ProcessResult;
}


interface MultipleTask {
  public function  process(): iterable;
}
```

Since your `BaseTask` includes nothing to help implement the class (only includes an abstract method, making it already very similar to an interface), move the `implements` to each of the concrete task classes:

```
class ExampleTask extends BaseTask implements Task
{ /** implementation **/ }

class ExampleMultipleTask extends BaseTask implements MultipleTask
{ /** implementation **/ }
```